# Mysql syntax error in preparedstatement

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

I have a simple prepared statement that updates the records in a MySQL database. The table, the column, the target attribute and the information are taken from textfields. First I made it without prepared statement, but the program was easily breakable if the user chose to insert quotes or %%$&^* other symbols.

Now Im getting this:

> UPDATE client SET 'full_name'=Martinajh WHERE
>   id='5'com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You
>   have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
>   ''selectedTable2' SET 'namec' = 'cellValue' WHERE id== 5' at line 1

```
String cellValue3 = String.valueOf( table.getValueAt(row, 0) );
int id = Integer.parseInt(cellValue3);
String selectedTable2 = (String) listOfTablesNames.getSelectedValue();
String cellValue = String.valueOf( table.getValueAt(row, column) );
String namec = table.getColumnName(column);
String query ="UPDATE ? SET ? = ? WHERE id== ?";
PreparedStatement preparedStmt = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(query);
preparedStmt.setString   (1, "selectedTable2");
preparedStmt.setString(2, "namec");
preparedStmt.setString(3, "cellValue");
preparedStmt.setInt(4, id);
preparedStmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: `WHERE id== ?` Try using a single equal sign here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't construct a preparedstatement with table name as a parameter. You need to contruct the SQL with string concatenation/placeholder with String.format. Prepared statement is for the column values not for table name.
In your case:

```
String query ="UPDATE `" + selectedTableVar + "` SET `" + fieldNameVar + "` = ? WHERE id = ?";
//...
preparedStmt.setString(1, "cellValue");
preparedStmt.setInt(2, id);
```

Also, `id = ?` as @C. Helling mentioned.

As for sanitizing `selectedTableVar` and `fieldNameVar` variables, I can't find a link right now, but you can do the research by yourself about what is a valid qualifier in MySQL... AFAIK, any UTF character is valid, most of special symbols may be a part of a valid table name etc. Using the syntax suggested above you should bother not allowing the ` character to prevent injection and I guess that's it. But it must be investigated.

Comment: It's generally a good idea to identifier escape those if there's a method for that internally.

Comment: It is, indeed. But I cannot recall one right now and I fail to google it rapidly. So let it be @Boombastic task :)

Comment: Thank you sir, I managed to solve everything after reading your answer.